# Ipython widget Dropdown including NaN values

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, ipywidgets

I have an ipython widget dropdown which includes NaN:

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
import numpy as np
widgets.Dropdown(description='Choose this:', options=[None, 'a', 'b', np.nan])
```

When I try to select NaN, I get the following error:

```
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
...

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
...
ValueError: nan not in array

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TraitError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
...
TraitError: Invalid selection: value not found
```

I removed the Tracebacks because the bot is forcing me to add more details because my post is "mostly code".

At first I thought we can only have literals in the dropdown, but using objects generally works fine.
What is so peculiar about NaN?

Comment: Works fine for me on ipywidgets 7.5.1 in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Mh, ok, I will test it on a different computer later today.

Comment: Tested on my personal laptop. Still no luck. I have the same ipywidgets version as confirmed with `pip show ipywidgets`. Did you copy exactly my code? The error only appears when you try to select the NaN.

Comment: OK I see the error now ,and even replacing the list with a dictionary causes issues. I suspect there is some validation issue with np.nan as a widget value.

What do you want to use the np.nan for? Filtering a dataframe?

Comment: I will actually share this notebook with a coworker and use the dropdown to get user input. I am comparing two dataframes and if there are differences, I am asking which value to use. ...and one of the values might be nan.

Comment: Then use some kind of placeholder value (such as the string 'nan') in your dropdown, and in your observe function, check for the presence of 'nan' as the value, and replace with an isna() call at that point.

You want to handle `np.nan` downstream differently anyway, as you don't test for nan with equality as you would do for any of your other string or integer choices:


`df['name'] == np.nan # wrong`


`df['name'].isna() # correct`

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. The part about handling NaN differently downstream is true but it still is very inconvenient, especially since pandas handles NaN quite cleverly in many functions out of the box (col.unique(), df.update(), ...). Anyways, the question will stay here, so maybe someone can enlighten us on why the dropdown behaves in this way.